# UK Post Code Location References

Tags: data, united-kingdom, postal-code

I have a spreadsheet data which only contain post code as location references. I want to map them to a point shapefile based on their postcodes. All I can think is to find a point data which have postcodes and coordinates on them, or a georeferenced postcode point data, and use join&relates to connect them with my spreadsheet but I don't know where to find such data.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Ordnance Survey provides some free open data on postcodes called 'Code-Point Open'.  It is a csv of the post-code with a lat long attribute.  I'd suggest getting hold of this data then extracting just the post-codes you're interested in.

[Information on the layer can be found here](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html), and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html#CODEPO).  Just need to fill in a form and they send you a link to download from

Answer (score 2):

If you want latitude and longitude you can use [Open Postcode Geo](https://www.getthedata.com/open-postcode-geo). I created and maintain this dataset - it is open data licensed on the same basis as Code-Point Open.

[Code-Point Open](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html) gives you northing and easting, but not latitude and longitude.